# getting selected values from an array of select box in to javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created dynamic select box using jquery. I have created the select box as an array name=`Child[]`. See my code

```
for(i=1;i<=val;i++){

            var newParagraph = $('<dl class="thirty fl"><dt>Child '+i+'</dt>  <dd><select name="child[]"><option value="">--select--</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option</select></dd></dl>');
                $('#childDynamic').append(newParagraph);
            }
```

In form validation section (in javascript), how I validate this select box? I don't know how to get the values from an array of select box using JavaScript

Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(You don't actually have an array of select elements, given that html doesn't have arrays. But anyway...)

If you use the name attribute as the selector you can get a jQuery object containing the select elements:

```
$('#childDynamic select[name="child\\[\\]"]')
```

...which you can then process as you see fit.

Because square brackets have special meaning in jQuery selectors they need to be escaped with backslashes, and to include backslashes in a string literal they need to be escaped too.

Anyway, I don't know what kind of validation you want to apply, but if you wanted to loop through each select and check its value in some way you could do something like this:

```
var valid = true;
$('#childDynamic select[name="child\\[\\]"]').each(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    // example validation: make sure something other than the default
    // blank value is selected
    if (val === "") {
        valid = false;
    }
});
if (!valid) {
   // do something
}
```